# Django rollback doesn't work

Tags: python, django

Using Django1.4.22 and 'autocommit' default is True. Since I can't change the default value, how can I turn it off temporarily so I can use rollback.
Background: I was writing a script for database data deletion, and I wanna test if it will work before I really delete it. So I use dry_run to test if it is deleted and then rollback.

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def run(self, dry_run):
    try:
        assert self.database in self.validate_values.keys()
        assert self.table in self.validate_values.values()
    except AssertionError as e:
        logger.error("%s or %s is not available. \n Error: %s" % (self.database, self.table, e.message))
        return

    self.cursor.execute(self.SELECT_PATTERN % self.PGDict)
    current_value = self.cursor.fetchall()

    if len(current_value) > 1:
        logger.error("You can only update one item at a time.\n Current value: %s" % current_value)
        return

    elif len(current_value) == 0:
        logger.error("No data.")
        return

    elif len(current_value) == 1:
        if dry_run:
            logger.warning("Data below will be deleted.\n")
            logger.info("Current value: %s" % current_value)

            transaction.savepoint()

            try:
                print current_value
                self.cursor.execute(self.DELETE_PATTERN % self.PGDict)
                self.cursor.execute(self.SELECT_PATTERN % self.PGDict)
                current_value = self.cursor.fetchall()
                assert len(current_value) == 0

                transaction.rollback()

                logger.info("Dry run successfully.")

                self.cursor.execute(self.SELECT_PATTERN % self.PGDict)

                current_value = self.cursor.fetchall()
                print current_value
                return current_value
            except AssertionError as e:
                logger.error("Dry run failed. \n Error: %s" % e.message)
                return

        else:
            logger.warning("Data deleting...\n")

            self.cursor.execute(self.DELETE_PATTERN % self.PGDict)
            self.cursor.execute(self.SELECT_PATTERN % self.PGDict)
            current_value = self.cursor.fetchall()

            try:
                assert len(current_value) == 0
                logger.info("Done.")
                return len(current_value)
            except AssertionError as e:
                logger.error("Deletion failed. \n Error: %s" % e.message)
                return

    else:
        logger.error("Value Error")
        return
```

and the test is below:

```
    def test_run_dry_run(self):
        actual = self.toolkit.run(dry_run=True)
        self.assertEqual(len(actual), 1)
        self.assertEqual(actual[0][0], 123456)
```

Comment: 'rollback doesn't work' isn't a very specific error. It's especially tricky to help because you're using such an old version of Django. Django 1.4 is years out of date, and the transaction APIs were overhauled in Django 1.5.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks! I deleted transaction.rollback() and called transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid) and seems like it did rollback but actually it didn't and I don't know why. I created a savepoint before deletion and it should rollback to where I did not do the deletion, right? But as long as I query the data again it's already deleted. And there's an error occurred: TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK.

Comment: @Alasdair Now I can rollback to where it should be! Thanks for that but still there's an error: TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK and I cannot seem to fix it.

Comment: As the error message suggests, you need to call `transaction.commit()` or `transaction.rollback()` to commit or rollback the transaction before the view returns.

Comment: @Alasdair I add ```if transaction.is_dirty(using='aa_assets'):
                    transaction.set_clean(using='aa_assets')``` to fix this problem and it's good to go. Thank you so much!